# Unable to run DeepAR Web SDK in React electron desktop app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, augmented-reality

I am trying to use DeepAR Web SDK in an Electron Desktop application with frontend built using React. DeepAR SDK is working fine in the React server running on Chrome Browser.

I am using DeepAR Web SDK for background segmentation and face tracking of user whose feed will come through the webcam. I added the Web SDK files of DeepAR and added it inside the main `index.html` file.

I am getting following error for the `deepar.wasm` file:

`GET http://localhost:9990/Users/prashantyadav/Projects/mydeskapp/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer/deepar.wasm net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

`wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': HTTP status code is not ok`

In the electron environment, the path of `deepar.wasm` file is getting converted into an absolute file path which results in the 404 error.

The problem is occurring from the fetching of `deepar.wasm` file from `deepar.js` sdk file through Electron environment.

Comment: same here...this SDK a blob of cxxx. The minute I do an import without writing zero code, my app has a build error.